# APIs in android for Bluetooth Immediate alert service in Find me profile

Tags: android, api, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an android application for 'Bluetooth find me profile'. I need to get all the android API's related to the immediate alert service in 'bluetooth find me profile'. In the case of 'Bluetooth find me profile', server will alert the client.So for developing the profiles i need to get the API's related to alerting the client.

Answer (score 1):

The Bluetooth Find me profile and immediate alert service are Bluetooth Smart porfiles/services. The normal Android APIs don't support Bluetooth Smart.

There's a few efforts on adding API's to Android to make them work with Bluetooth Smart profiles: http://developer.motorola.com/docs/bluetooth-low-energy-api/ 
http://code.google.com/p/broadcom-ble/